# Calling DLL function in Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am having trouble understanding on how to call dll functions from an existing dll in Python.

```
OTAClient = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\PATH\OTAClient.dll")
connect = OTAClientDLL.TDConnection()
```

---

```
exceptions.AttributeError: function 'TDConnection' not found
```

I read something the name being mangled by the compiler.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLL was actually a COM DLL.
comtypes is needed to use this type of DLL instead of ctypes.
Make sure to [download comtypes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes/files/)

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject

OTAClientDLL = comtypes.client.GetModule("C:\PATH\OTAClient.dll")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the compiler mangling the function names. There are two ways of getting around this issue:

1. fix the code to tell the compiler not to mangle names. (Lookup adding extern reference)
2. find the mangled name and call that from python (See the below description)

Read the following (from http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)

Sometimes, dlls export functions with names which aren’t valid Python identifiers, like "??2@YAPAXI@Z". In this case you have to use getattr() to retrieve the function:

```
>>>
>>> getattr(cdll.msvcrt, "??2@YAPAXI@Z") 
<_FuncPtr object at 0x...>
>>>
```

On Windows, some dlls export functions not by name but by ordinal. These functions can be accessed by indexing the dll object with the ordinal number:

```
>>>
>>> cdll.kernel32[1] 
<_FuncPtr object at 0x...>
>>> cdll.kernel32[0] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "ctypes.py", line 310, in __getitem__
    func = _StdcallFuncPtr(name, self)
AttributeError: function ordinal 0 not found
>>>
```

If you are not sure what the function name might be, then look up link.exe dumpbin.exe. These are found with Visual Studio installations and they dump all the functions available in the dll. You can run a grep over the result.

Comment: I looked into this documentation before, this did not help.